# Serialize data for Flot Pie compatibility

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, flot

Even though the data I am passing from my server to client is same as Flot accepts but it is not being drawn. There is also an error on the line where I am trying to parse the returned string JSON. Code Below:

```
    //server_processing.aspx.cs
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetPieData()
    {
        List<PieData> pieData = new List<PieData>();
        pieData.Add(new PieData { label = "A", data = 40 });
        pieData.Add(new PieData { label = "B", data = 40 });
        pieData.Add(new PieData { label = "C", data = 20 });

        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        var writer = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter);
        writer.QuoteName = false;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, pieData);
        writer.Close();
        var json = stringWriter.ToString();
        return json;
    }

//PieData.cs
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class PieData
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string label { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public int data { get; set; }
}

<%-- Charts.aspx --%>
<script type="text/javascript">
var options = { series: { pie: {show: true} } };
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "server_processing.aspx/GetPieData",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
            var jsObj = [];
            //Error on the line below
            //0x800a03f6 - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid character
            jsObj.push($.parseJSON(msg.d)); // [{label:"A",data:40},{label:"B",data:40},{label:"C",data:20}] 

            $.plot($("#piechart"), jsObj, options);
        }
    });
});
```

I did the same thing for the Flot Line Chart and it worked perfectly. Can someone please kindly point me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Can you log jsObj to the console and show us exactly what the data looks like?

Comment: Actually that is the line where the error occurs. When parsing to JSON. But in Internet Explorer console for sent data which is `msg` I get  `[object Object]`.

Comment: You should probably mention in your question that there was an error, and provide any info that you have about it; the way you described the issue it sounded like the plot was just silently failing.  Also, log msg.d, since that's what is being parsed.

Comment: `msg.d = [{label:"A",data:40},{label:"B",data:40},{label:"C",data:20}]`. It matches the data that is required for Flot Pie [link](http://www.pureexample.com/flot-pie-chart.html). Could you please tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. I commented out the previous code and inserted new ones to make the differences apparent.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var options = { series: { pie: {show: true} } };
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "server_processing.aspx/GetPieData",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            //var jsObj = [];
            //jsObj.push($.parseJSON(msg.d));
            var data = ($.parseJSON(msg.d);
            $.plot($("#piechart"), data, options);
        }
    });
});
</script>

//server_processing.aspx.cs
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetPieData()
    {
        List<PieData> pieData = new List<PieData>();
        pieData.Add(new PieData { label = "A", data = 40 });
        pieData.Add(new PieData { label = "B", data = 40 });
        pieData.Add(new PieData { label = "C", data = 20 });

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string returnArray = js.Serialize(pieData);
        return returnArray;

        //var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        //var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        //var writer = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter);
        //writer.QuoteName = false;
        //serializer.Serialize(writer, pieData);
        //writer.Close();
        //var json = stringWriter.ToString();
        //return json;
    }
```

Since, I was pushing parsed data into already initialized array. It seemed that the data was being pushed on the first index which is not acceptable format for Flot pie and thus, the exception and no Pie chart on screen. Please feel free to correct my explanation.